# session became null in asp.net mvc view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

In Session_OnStart() method of my asp.net mvc application, I store a value in session like this :

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["sid"] = GUID.New();
```

But in some view, If I want to use that session, most of the times, it says that it is null:

```
@{
var item= HttpContext.Current.Session["sid"];
}
```

would you help me please ?

Comment: are you able to access session in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code with a little modification :

In the Global.asax :

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
     HttpContext.Current.Session["sid"] = new Guid();
}
```

Index.cshtml :

```
@{
    var item = HttpContext.Current.Session["sid"];
}
```

It worked for me. Result in the view => 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000